# In Glade, how do I set a widget size (i.e. minimum and maximum)?

Tags: application-development, resize, glade

I want to set the size of one of the widgets of an app developed with Quickly and Glade.
I know how to set a minimum size in the 'Common' tab, with 'Width request' and 'Height request'. But I would like to set also the maximum size. How do I do that ?

That way, I will also have the possibility to set the size entirely, if I force minimum = maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can set a maximum size as size requirements adjust due to things such as translations and screen resolutions. If you need a widget to not get beyond a certain size, size it in proportion to the other widgets.